# Accessing data on downloaded plist (xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am quite new to xcode, and I am sure this is a fairly easy question but I couldn't find the right info on google..

so I have a plist online and I use the following code to download the plist:

```
 farmerlist = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.mysite.com/my.plist" ]];
```

after I get the file I manually print the array and I get the following:
Printing description of farmerlist:

```
<__NSCFArray 0x78a9600>(
{
    AccountName = "'test'";
    AccountNumber = "'ta'";
    Bank = "'test'";
    Branch = "'ta'";
    CardNumber = "'121'";
},
```

but whenever I try to access farmerlist[0] the app crashes,

any ideas?

Comment: A .plist is a dictionary; which holds key-value pairs, where the keys are all strings, in your situation.

Comment: pls post ur code that u tried ti fetch farmerlist[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your .plist format , if you try to access 'Branch', code should be...

```
NSArray *farmerlist = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.mysite.com/my.plist" ]];

NSString *firstBranchName = nil;
if(farmerlist.count > 0 )
{    
     firstBranchName = [[farmerlist objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Branch"];    
}    
NSLog(@"Branch : %@",firstBranchName );
```

Comment: I get build error:
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_NSlog", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)